# Calling startService from different app when service name is not known in advance

Tags: android, service, manifest

I am trying to call a service via startService while the caller and called are not in the same application. I don't get an exception but the onBind and onCreate on the service side are not called. The issue here is that the service name is received on the fly so I cannot define it in the caller's manifest file in advance. Can someone refer me to a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the service methods were called but writing to the logger inside the service methods failed for some reason. This is why it looked like the methods were not called.